# Is it good to set cpufreq as high as possible all the time?

Tags: central-processing-unit

Originally this question was about why I have cpuinfo mhz of 1400 when I purchased a 2300 mhz server cpu.

With the help of HBruijn (thx!) and using `cpufreq-info` tools I found out my real specs:

```
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: powernow-k8
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 8.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 2.40 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.40 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: userspace, powersave, conservative, ondemand, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 2.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
```

Question:

Is it good to let **the driver decide** how much power the cpu has (1400mhz on low usage),
**or** is it better for a server to set the frequency to **as high as possible** (2300mhz) **permanently**?

Comment: in addition to my earleir answer: /sys/devices/system/cpu*/ and a quite interesting SuSe Linux manual: http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-tuning_sd_draft/cha.tuning.power.html

Comment: @HBruijn thx for your answer and comment, that was very helpful yet. I changed the question a bit

Comment: At the moment I'm without access to a Debian box, so I can't check myself, but take a look at the Debian Wiki https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer:

A little bit of everything I would say.

The AMD [3280 CPU product description](http://products.amd.com/en-us/OpteronCPUDetail.aspx?id=787&f1=AMD%20Opteron%E2%84%A2%203200%20Series%20Processor&f2=&f3=Yes&f4=&f5=1024&f6=AM3%2b&f7=B2&f8=32nm&f9=&f10=5200&f11=&)  specifies 8 cores and a base frequency of 2400 Hz. which doesn't match with your /proc/cpuinfo nor with the 8x2.3 GHz on your invoice...

---

**How to do CPU frequency scaling to conserve power?**

Paraphrased from https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling

```
apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Edit /etc/default/cpufrequtils (you might need to create it if it doesn't exist) and specify the governor with the GOVERNOR variable:

```
# /etc/default/cpufrequtils 
# get valid values from cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
# typically: userspace conservative powersave ondemand performance
GOVERNOR="conservative"
```

---

**To scale your CPU frequency or not?**

It depends. It always does, really.

IBM developer works has a series about Linux power consumption, tuning and CPU throttling [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-1/) [part2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-2/) [part3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-3). Very informative.

Conclusion, the performance governor gave the highest performance and the lowest latency, but looking at the performance per watt it was the worst performer.

So from an ecological perspective use conservative. If you pay for your own power consumption, do so as well. If you need maximum performance and power is included with your rackspace, then set it to maximum all the time.